# Adding a new developer to a devops team

Tags: azure-devops

The new user setup their account at the tail end of last week and today we added them via the documented invite mechanism to join our dev team using the Microsoft account email address.

they have received the email and clicked the accept link in it and logged in to the portal @ {mycorp}.visualstudio.com and confirmed they can see the dashboards, boards, ect.

Having put them in the same team as the rest of us which is a member of the contributors default group for the project in question I was then expecting to open up VS and pull the latest from the repo root.

The user can see everything but the repo it seems so I hit a wall.

How do I fix this because as far as I can tell they have all the permissions that the rest of the team has?

Comment: ​Ok figured it out ... he was setup as using a VS sub but the VS sub was not found. Shame I can't close this for a couple days.

Comment: You can convert your comment into an answer, it can help other community members who get the same issues more easily to find the solution and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: I can't until the required period of time has passed. I will do it though after the 2 days ... ok it's let post the answer now, just have to wait a further 24 hours to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​Ok figured it out ... he was setup as using a VS sub but the VS sub was not found.